# Converter 'const std::string' para 'std::string &'

Tags: c++, lista

Estou com um erro e gostaria de dicas para solucioná-lo

Tenho meu struct Node dentro da classe DLList:

```
struct Node
{
    Type m_data;
    Node *m_next, *m_prev;

    Node(Type& v, Node* _prev) : m_data(v), m_prev(_prev), m_next(nullptr) {}
};

Node *m_head, *m_tail;
int m_size;
```

E a função:

```
template<typename Type>
void DLList<Type>::addHead(const Type& v)
{
    Node* node = new Node(v, m_head);

    node->m_data = v;
    node->m_next = m_head;
    m_head = node;

    ++m_size;
}
```

Porém quando criando o Node* node passando os parâmetros, o compilador está devolvendo este erro:
*'DLList::Node::Node(DLList::Node &&)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'const std::string' to 'std::string &'*

Os parâmetros passados, estão vindo da main():

```
DLList<string> list;
DLList<string> list2;
DLList<string>* list3;
DLLIter<string> iter(list);
DLList<int>* testPointer;
```

Answer (score 0):

Acabei de achar o erro... Falta de atenção mesmo.

Meu construtor do Node está preparado para receber apenas 'Type& v', enquanto isso estou tentando passar 'const Type& v', o que logicamente não funcionaria.

Novo struct Node:

```
struct Node
{
    Type m_data;
    Node *m_next, *m_prev;

    Node(const Type& v, Node* _prev) : m_data(v), m_prev(_prev), m_next(nullptr)    {}
};
```